# New induction CB tripping

Tags: electrical

Just moved into a house that has Hager CB's all labelled. Brilliant. The one that is currently causing me problems is the one for what is labelled 'gas hob' with 6A Hager circuit breaker. I fitted a Neff Induction hob rated at 4600w and works ok with 1 hob on. Try any more and it trips. Quite prepared to upgrade it to 20w CB, but how do I know what rating the wire is between the hob and CB?

Comment: Where are you on this planet? Also, can you turn off the breaker and get us photos of the wiring at the socket the hob plugs into?

Comment: Absolutely correct, that is why you think *before* changing the breaker.  Generally wires and breakers are matched pairs, if the breaker is 6A the wire is probably that little 1,0mm angel hair stuff Brits use on lighting circuits.  Just right for a *gas* hob.

Comment: Harper, thanks for the conformation. It's only roughly 15 feet to circuit board from the hob, but I'll get a sparks in to re-wire...ThreePhaseEel...can do without idiotic responses...

Comment: ThreePhasEel..afterthought..maybe you meant, where are you in the world..bit more apt. Anyway UK based..apologies if you weren't being sarcastic.

Answer (score 1):

Given it's a hob, I'll guess UK or related, 240VAC countries. Doesn't really matter much, the answer holds for wherever you are.

Basically, a gas "hob" or cooktop or stove or range does not use much electrical power. So it will tend to have a small breaker and small, low capacity wiring. The heat comes from burning gas, not electricity.

Changing a gas hob to an electrical induction hob will require a complete refit from the breaker panel to the hob in order to have properly sized wire and breaker for the vastly larger electrical load, as you are now trying to make heat with electricity.

Comment: Many thanks, I'll get a 'sparks' friend to come and look at it Inthink...